# Nginx proxy ssl broken pipe in https requests longer than 5 seconds

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have nginx sitting as reverse proxy in front of a rails app on unicorn.

We have not overwritten any of the timeout defaults.

The problem I have is that:

When requesting a page that takes over 5 seconds over http it works fine.

When requesting a specific page that takes over 5 seconds over httpS I get a 324 (empty response by the server)
When requesting any other page on the system it works just fine over https.

I can confirm that is a timing issue because I stripped the templates out and put a sleep 6 to make the template wait to render empty.

The request has couple of subrequests to js and css, these work fine when called individually.

The nginx error log shows a socket reading error in the case of the problem url.

when in http does the template rendering and the subrequests,

when in the failed url on https, it sends the request upstream *twice* but dies there, without sending the subrequests.
(the rails app claims it rendered it ok)

The weird thing is that it sends the original request twice to the upstream,
then dies,

Logs and configuration file follows,

**NGINX ERROR LOG** (only on HTTPS when reading that specific url that takes long to render):

2012/11/06 15:05:00 [info] 5717#0: *4012 SSL_write() failed (SSL:) (32: Broken pipe) while reading upstream, client: 10.2.20.98, server: cloud.zia4buildings.com, request: "GET /admin/datasets HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/datasets", host: "cloud.zia4buildings.com", referrer: "https://cloud.zia4buildings.com/admin/sage_categories"

2012/11/06 15:05:03 [info] 5717#0: *4027 SSL_write() failed (SSL:) (32: Broken pipe) while reading upstream, client: 10.2.20.98, server: cloud.zia4buildings.com, request: "GET /admin/datasets HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/datasets", host: "cloud.zia4buildings.com", referrer: "https://cloud.zia4buildings.com/admin/sage_categories"

**[edit]** 
The problem is a time out on the https proxy pass,
if i throw a sleep 6 seconds in any page (even a super light one), then the https request fails.

```
**APPLICATION LOGS:**
(my comments in (-- --)
**HTTP:**

Started GET "/admin/datasets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 09:19:40 -0700
  Processing by Admin::DatasetsController#index as HTML
(--  lots of these ok --)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (5.4ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_admin_links.html.erb (4.1ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (5694.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5704ms (Views: 5171.9ms | ActiveRecord: 531.4ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/dyn_stylesheets/dynamic.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 09:15:31 -0700
  Processing by DynStylesheetsController#index as CSS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"dynamic"}
Exist fragment? views/rating_system_css_colors (1.4ms)
Read fragment views/rating_system_css_colors (0.1ms)
Exist fragment? views/leed_category_css_colors (0.4ms)
Read fragment views/leed_category_css_colors (0.0ms)
Exist fragment? views/sage_category_css_colors (0.3ms)
Read fragment views/sage_category_css_colors (0.0ms)
Exist fragment? views/node_css_colors (3.3ms)
Read fragment views/node_css_colors (0.0ms)
Rendered dyn_stylesheets/dynamic.css.erb (9.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 12.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
(-- EOF HTTP success request --)



**HTTPS:**

Started GET "/admin/datasets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 09:20:44 -0700
  Processing by Admin::DatasetsController#index as HTML
Rendered admin/datasets/_set_field.html.erb (15.8ms)
(--  lots of these ok --)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_admin_links.html.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (5973.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5982ms (Views: 5419.4ms | ActiveRecord: 561.5ms)

(-- (here starts a second, identical request without no apparent reason) --)

Started GET "/admin/datasets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 09:20:47 -0700
  Processing by Admin::DatasetsController#index as HTML
Rendered admin/datasets/_set_field.html.erb (15.9ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_set_field.html.erb (0.5ms)
(--  lots of these ok --)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/_dataset_category.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_admin_links.html.erb (4.1ms)
Rendered admin/datasets/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (5944.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5955ms (Views: 5419.8ms | ActiveRecord: 549.8ms)

(-- here the browser gets the error 324, empty response --)
```

**CONF:**

This is the classic configuration:

```
upstream unicorn_server {
  # this socket is set up on the config/unicorn.rb file
  server unix:/home/sage/apps/sage/production/shared/.unicorn.sock;
}

server {
  listen       80; 

  root /home/sage/apps/sage/production/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
      break;
    }
  }

}

server {
  listen       localhost:443; 
  listen       10.2.20.84:443; 

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/cert.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/cert.com.key;

  root /home/sage/apps/sage/production/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointer in the right direction much appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

the culprit was haproxy which was sitting in front of the whole stack in our firewall.
and thus sending these timeouts,